# Filter by list's element in payload

Tags: python, vector-database, qdrant, qdrantclient

In Qdrant DB I have a payload containing a list. How can I filter results of a search limiting to the ones where the list contain a specific element?

As example, if the set of points is:

```json
[
  { "id": 1, "Fruit": ["apple", "banana", "orange"] },
  { "id": 2, "Fruit": ["pear", "orange" ] },
  { "id": 3, "test": "empty" },
  { "id": 4,  "Fruit": ["apple", "orange", "pear"] }
]
```

And I want to filter the results containing at least an Apple AND an Orange, i.e. the ones with ID 1 and 4.

How can I build such filter?

I already had a look at the documentation [at this link](https://qdrant.tech/documentation/concepts/filtering/), without success.

In the docs there is no my case. What I tried is:

```
Filter(should=[FieldCondition(key='Fruit', match=MatchValue(value='Banana'), range=None, geo_bounding_box=None, geo_radius=None, values_count=None), FieldCondition(key='Fruit', match=MatchValue(value='Apple'), range=None, geo_bounding_box=None, geo_radius=None, values_count=None)], must=None, must_not=None)
```

But the result that I know is in the DB does not show up

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried from the official documentation that did not work ? Was the filtering not applied and the same results were returned ?

Comment: In the docs there is no my case.
What I tried is `Filter(should=[FieldCondition(key='flagged_persons', match=MatchValue(value='Banana'), range=None, geo_bounding_box=None, geo_radius=None, values_count=None), FieldCondition(key='flagged_persons', match=MatchValue(value='Apple'), range=None, geo_bounding_box=None, geo_radius=None, values_count=None)], must=None, must_not=None)`
But the result that I know is in the DB does not show up

Comment: Where is `key='flagged_persons'` coming from? Did you mean to use `key='Fruit'`?

Comment: exactely, key-'fruit', sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created some dashboard console queries to setup your example.

### Example setup

Create a fruit collection.

```
PUT collections/fruit
{
  "vectors": {
    "size": 3,
    "distance": "Cosine"
  }
}
```

Create points in the fruit collection.

```
PUT collections/fruit/points
{
  "batch": {
    "ids": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
    ],
    "vectors": [
      [
        0, 1, 2
      ],
      [3, 2, -1],
      [-1, -1, -1],
      [0, 2, 3]
    ],
    "payloads": [
      {
        "Fruit": [
          "apple",
          "banana",
          "orange"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Fruit": [
          "pear",
          "orange"
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": "empty"
      },
      {
        "Fruit": [
          "apple",
          "orange",
          "pear"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Search for points where payload includes "apple" and  "orange" in "Fruit" field.

```
POST collections/fruit/points/search
{
  "limit": 10,
  "vector": [
    0,
    1,
    2
  ],
  "filter": {
    "must": [
      {
        "key": "Fruit",
        "match": {
          "text": "apple"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Fruit",
        "match": {
          "text": "orange"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "with_payload": true
}
```

> Providing [a list of filter conditions in the must filter behaves similarly to an and](https://qdrant.tech/documentation/concepts/filtering/#must).

This translates to Python as:

```py
Filter(
    must=[
        FieldCondition(key='Fruit[]', match=MatchValue(value='apple'),
        FieldCondition(key='Fruit[]', match=MatchValue(value='orange'),
    ]
)
```

Comment: To simplify this answer, you can simply use the regular 'Match' to also match an item in a list: https://qdrant.tech/documentation/concepts/filtering/#match